# Facebook Session lost connection When force close the app in IOS 7.0.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios7, session-timeout

Facebook Session lost connection When force close the app in IOS 7.0.3.  Its happening only on iOS 7.0.3.  It is strange behaviour.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe it is problem in facebook's SDK.
try to update it, or wait to new version.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to maintain.

Comment: Hi, I am running the same issue here. have you solved it ?